# NodeJS add the authorization button to Swagger Documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, swagger

I need to be able to add the following button to Swagger's UI interface so that the testers can add the "Bearer token" header and test the apis.

[image]

My swagger's option definition is:

```
module.exports = {
    definition: {
        openapi: "3.0.3",
        info: {
            title: "APIs",
            version: "1.0.0",
        },
        servers: [
            {
                url: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`
            }
        ],
        securityDefinitions: {
            bearerAuth: {
                type: 'apiKey',
                name: 'Authorization',
                scheme: 'bearer',
                in: 'header',
            },
        }
    },
    apis: ["./routes/*.js", "app.js"],
};
```

and my endpoint is as follows:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/users/test:
 *  post:
 *      security: 
 *          - Bearer: []
 *      summary: test authorization
 *      tags: [User]
 *      description: use to test authorization JWT
 *      responses:
 *          '200':  
 *              description: success
 *          '500':
 *                  description: Internal server error
 */

router.post('/test', verifyJWT(), async (req, res) => {
    res.send('hi');
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using OAS v3? You have errors in your declarations, for example `securityDefinitions` is now called `securitySchemes` and it is inside `components`.

Check https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/

When you fix your schema, then  you add a `security` property to your path to protect it with a security schema so that you'll get the green `Authorize` button.

```
components:
  securitySchemes:

    BearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
```

```
paths:
   /api/users/test:
     post:
       security: 
         - BearerAuth: []
```

Comment: yes turns out that I am using older pieces of codes. thank you so much

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually didnot occur to me that my securitySchemes is not placed inside components. Its a blunder from my side.

Comment: FYI, Prefixing the token with "Bearer" is not required while setting it in swagger UI as its already mentioned that scheme is a "bearer" in "securitySchemes"

Answer (score 1):

For swagger-ui-express 4.6.3 in Node project

1. Add securityDefinitions in swagger.json file as below.

*Note : bearerAuth must be same in security parameter

2.Add security parameter in every path or API in swagger.json file

```
 "securityDefinitions": {
  "bearerAuth": {
    "type": "apiKey",
    "in": "header",
    "name": "Authorization",
    "description": "Bearer token to access these api endpoints",
    "scheme": "bearer"
  }
}

"security": [
      {
        "bearerAuth": []
      }
    ]
```